# How to merge 2 nested lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested, nested-lists

I want to merge 2 lists:

```
list1 = ['a', ['b', ['c', ['lol', [{'s': '21'}]]]]]
list2 = ['a', ['f', ['d', [{'x': '22'}]]]]]
```

The expected result:

```
['a', ['b', ['c', ['lol', [{'s': '21'}]]]], ['f', ['d', [{'x': '22'}]]]]
```

I tried get by key, but I didn't get what I expected.

Comment: What does "tried get by key" mean?

Comment: I think both list2 and the expected result do not have balanced brackets, please check again.

Comment: tried get by key -> I mean recursive function like 
    for key in list2:
        if key in list1:
           recursion here etc

Comment: Did you mean to drop the first 'a' from list2, otherwise surely just list3 = list1 + list2 gives the desired result?

Comment: @IainD in this example yes, but I want universal function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear to me how you intend to identify duplications at nested levels but at the first level, you could use a list comprehension to filter the items of the second list excluding those that are in the first one:

```
list1 = ['a', ['b', ['c', ['lol', [{'s': '21'}]]]]]
list2 = ['a', ['f', ['d', [{'x': '22'}]]]]

list3 = list1 + [i for i in list2 if i not in list1 ]

print(list3)
['a', ['b', ['c', ['lol', [{'s': '21'}]]]], ['f', ['d', [{'x': '22'}]]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a function that recursively run through your lists and merge their elements together

```
def merge(list1, list2):
    if not list1:
        return list2
    if not list2:
        return list1

    merged_list = []

    if isinstance(list1[0], list) and isinstance(list2[0], list):
        merged_list.append(merge(list1[0], list2[0]))
    else:
        merged_list.append(list1[0])

    merged_list.extend(merge(list1[1:], list2[1:]))

    return merged_list

list1 = ['a', ['b', ['c', ['lol', [{'s': '21'}]]]]]
list2 = ['a', ['f', ['d', [{'x': '22'}]]]]

merged = merge(list1, list2)
print(merged)
```

Comment: The result of this function is ['a', ['b', ['c', ['lol', [{'s': '21'}]]]]]
It lost ['f', ['d', [{'x': '22'}]]]

Answer (score 0):

the above answer could not handle extending the list elements to the second list.

```
def merge_lists(list1, list2):
    if not list1:
        return list2
    if not list2:
        return list1

    merged_list = []
    if isinstance(list1[0], list) and isinstance(list2[0], list):
        merged_list.extend([merge_lists(list1[0], list2[0])])
    else:
        merged_list.extend([list1[0]])

    merged_list.extend(merge_lists(list1[1:], list2))
    return merged_list
```

Hope it helps! :D